# Find column name of active cell within ListObject in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table defined in Excel as a ListObject:

[image]

In VbA, I can access rows and columns using `ListObject("table1").ListRows` or `ListObject("table1").ListColumns`

In one of my subs, I wan't to know the active cell's column name.  And because the columns could be moved around, I want this to be dynamic.

For example, in the previous image, let's say I clicked on a cell of the third column.
I'd like to have a function that tells me the column name associated with that cell in the current ListObject.

In this case it would return `Line Desc.`

I tried to use a spy to find an object path that would allow me to figure out the column name, but I couldn't find any.

Before I start building a function that will do just that, I wanted to make sure I didn't miss anything in VbA objects repository.

Any idea if there is a built-in way to find the active cell's column name?

Thanks

Note: If I run out of time and create a function, I will post it here.

**EDIT**
*Here's what I have found so far:*

```
Function ColumnName(byVal Target as Range)
    If Sheets("Equipements").Listobjects("tMain").Active then
        ColumnName = ListObjects("tMain").HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, Target.Column).Value
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible issue with your method occurs when the ListObject doesn't start from Column A.

Con: Fixed to the table "tMain" only, cannot use on any other tables.

You can try this (if Target is more than 1 cell, only the top left cell is used):

```
Option Explicit

Function ColumnName(ByRef Target As Range) As String
    If Not Target.ListObject Is Nothing Then
        ColumnName = Intersect(Target.ListObject.HeaderRowRange, Target.EntireColumn).Value
    Else
        ColumnName = ""
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thx PatricK for the correction, definitely more useful that way!